# Как упростить этот код?

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Есть код

```
var znak = parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html()) || 0,
    lng0 = znak;
var znac = setInterval(function (){
   znak = lng0 = parseFloat($('td').eq(2).html());
},2000);
var znak1 = parseFloat($('td').eq(3).html()) || 0,
    lat1 = znak1;
var znac = setInterval(function (){
   znak1 = lat1 = parseFloat($('td').eq(3).html());
},2000);
```

C помощью которого получаю данные, и, если данные еще не получены, то  я устанавливаю первоначальное значение `0`.

Код мне очень помог в проекте, но у меня будет около 50-100 таких маркеров, и находить каждом из них значения - не вариант...

Как можно улучшить этот код ???

Comment: в прошлом вопросе я уже писал как нужно эти интервалы поменять, и заменить их вообще на один интервал

Comment: Убрать жиквери и использовать ванильку

Comment: можешь ссылку дать ?

Comment: можно ссылку на вашу ваньльку ?)

Comment: Ахах, засчитано)

Comment: я посмотрел)вньлька это фрейм ворк и я не хочу сейчас с жука на ваниль так как я с жуком вего 1 недельку работаю .мне еще хотяб 1 месяц опыта с ним потом можно дальше шагать а так перебегать неее слишком сложно окажется

Comment: ваниль не в плане фреймворк, а чистый джс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, по порядку:

Сперва, заменить этот транслит на что-нибудь менее травмирующее зрение и психику.

Затем, объединить все действия под интервалами в *ОДИН* интервал, в котором будут оббегаться все эти "маркеры", как было неоднократно предложено ранее.

После неплохо было бы вынести *МНОГОКРАТНО* используемый функционал в, соответственно, фукнцию. Не очень понимаю суть всего происходящего, но если так будет угодно, все что делается до интервала в одну функцию, все, что после - в другую.

Ну и как опять же указали ранее, пользоваться [VanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/) - инструмент хоть и сложный в освоении, но как только познаешь - откроется невообразимая мощь этого гиганта программирования.